# NEMA 14-30 to IEC C14 power cable?

Tags: cables

I have a 2000W power supply running a battery charger that I use mostly for charging LiPo batteries for R/C aircraft. I've got this all mounted in a carrying case with a common "PC power socket" (IEC-60320 C14) mounted on the outside of the case. I currently run this from a 20A 120VAC circuit.

I'm going to be moving things around in the garage, including moving a washer & dryer along with adding some circuits to the electrical panel. This got me thinking about a dedicated 240V plug for the "charge box". I know the PSU will handle 240VAC, in fact I can't get the full output of the PSU at 120. The C14 socket I have mounted in the charge box says it's rated up to 250VAC. So far so good.

I have been thinking that I would just install a NEMA 14-30 socket when I do the garage work, then I would buy or make a NEMA 14-40 to IEC C13 power cable. Is there any reason this won't work? Is there a different plug I should be using in the garage wall? I'll still want to power the charge box 120V when I'm not at home so I would prefer to leave the C14 socket if I can. If I do change it, I'll want something I can plug both into my new 240V circuit at home and standard US 120V  NEMA 5-15 sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a 14-30. This is rated for 30 amps and if protected by a 30A breaker, a 20 amp cord/connector would not be protected properly.

The better choice is a NEMA 6-20 which is 240V 20A rated. You can buy pre-built 6-20 to C14 cables.